# Unable to run the most basic query in cosmosdb Data Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

The default query in a new panel is `select * from c`

[image]

But when I create a new query in a new panel , that does not work?

[image]

Error text:

> Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":15,"end":16},"code":"SC1001","message":"Syntax error, incorrect syntax near '*'."}]} ActivityId: b5f1fde9-f18f-48c3-aa0b-e0dd97067e0f, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.14.0

**Update** Did this work or fail? There are conflicting messages. If it worked:

- why is there an error message
- where are those 12 rows?

[image]

Comment: That should not be the case, can you paste what do you see on the more details?

Comment: @Sajeetharan  I updated the question.  Maybe it worked?  But there are two serious issues if that were the case..

Comment: May be it's one off , are you getting it often?

Comment: No i've tried a dozen times , I am unable to get it to work

Comment: can you please edit with the correct error message, the syntax error

Comment: Your query is worked. Create new query tab and run it.

Comment: I got that issue yesterday. Prolly something  broken by MS .

Comment: @Sajeetharan - please don't add tags that are solely for product support issue tracking (since Stack Overflow isn't a product support site). I removed this tag, accordingly. Also see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: @WestCoastProjects - please provide the full message, not a partial screenshot. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) - include properly-formatted text, as actual text.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this appears to be some type of bug report (based on answer) and should be reported through vendor-specific channels

Comment: @DavidMakogon  It is not the case that bugs can not be reported on SOF: I do that for various vendor products regularly.   I may/may not have opportunity/time at the moment to submit the formal bug report: if /when I or another do that then the answer can be updated with the bug specifics.  If this gets closed I will follow up on meta.

Comment: This is absolutely not the place to report bugs. It's not a programming problem - you seem to have found some type of portal issue. Microsoft has specific channels to report such things. But no, it's not something valid here. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: I ran into a problem using a programming related tool .  That is on topic for tens of K's of questions of SOF .  I looked at that link provided and the "off-topic" items are such things as getting logons etc specific to a given user.   We agree that the next steps would be to follow up on an msft site. But it does not invalidate the process to this point"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in the *CosmosDB Data Explorer for Azure*. I have created a new panel and successfully shown results in it. It does not really matter which query, as long as it is valid. Here is what I used:

```
SELECT  c.registered ?? '-' as registered, c.lastName ?? '-' as lastName, 
    c.id, c._ts from c
```

[image]

After an error occurs the data output panel no longer is displayed and instead the error remains there .. permanently for that Sql Editor tab. Notice the query below is precisely the same as in the prior screenshot. But the error from a prior query is still shown instead.

I am using *chrome* on *macOS* .

[image]